# Default Gateway is skipped when adding an additional IP address

Tags: ip, gateway, route

I'm currently faced with an issue were when adding an addition IP address, Tracert results to intended IP address but skips the gateway and goes straight to that IP as the 1st/last hop.But when I remove the added IP, then the gateway appears

This, unfortunately messes a couple of things i.e. IIS sites
How can I resolve this issue

Server 1

Network Adapter 1

```
IP address: 192.168.2.10
Subnet Mask: 255.255.0.0
Gateway: 192.168.2.1
```

Additional IP address: `193.168.2.10`
Subnet Mask: `255.255.255.0`

Server 2

Network Adapter 1

```
IP address: 193.168.2.11
Subnet Mask: 255.255.0.0
Gateway: 193.168.2.1
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: This question doesn't make a lot of sense. Can you explain why you're trying to do what you're doing?

Comment: We have a web server that hosts multiple sites and has multiple IPs assigned to it.There are also multiple SSL bindings some of which are using their own public IPs. The problem is that one of the site, we added an IP that is on the same range as the APP server and then noticed that doing so messes up some sites i.e. within Default Web Sites. I'm not 100% sure how things interact but I know that the 1st server (Web server) communicates with the 2nd server (APP server), and that if the trace excludes the Gateway then some sites will be down but, when the added IP is removed then the rest is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working like that because from the server prospective, the 193.168.2.11 is on the same subnet as 193.168.2.10, so the connection is not getting routed at all.

What you could try is to add a static route to that destination IP:

```
route add 193.168.2.11 MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.2.1
```

Comment: Why would you even force a connection to a server on the same subnet to go through a router? That just doesn't make sense at all